# WCF Client Implementation, is there way to keep services and end-point detail in class library app.config rather then web.config for ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-client

I have .NET project in which I have APP.Client.Proxy class library project, responsible to implement WCF for client side so all the services and end-point configuration details are there and then I have another ASP.NET MVC project using these services implementation i.e. from controller. Now if I put services and end-point detail in app.config for class library project then it do not work, complaining about cannot find end-point but do work if I put end-point configuration detail in web.config for MVC web application.

My question is there way that I keep the services and end-point detail separate in app.config in class library rather then web.config

Comment: The app domain uses one config file when executing. while app setting and connection strings sections allow for referencing `file` and `configSource` respectively you could look into if the same applies for wcf config section

Comment: check http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/configsource-attribute-on-system-servicemodel-section or https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2009/11/03/separating-out-wcf-configuration-into-multiple-files-with-configsource/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app domain uses one config file when executing. while app setting and connection strings sections allow for referencing external file and configSource respectively.

After some quick GoogleFu I cam across these two articles

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/configsource-attribute-on-system-servicemodel-section

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2009/11/03/separating-out-wcf-configuration-into-multiple-files-with-configsource/

The crux of it is that you cannot leave it in the class library config but you can still separate them out into external config files.

```xml
<configuration>
  <!-- other code removed for brevity -->  
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services configSource="Services.config" >

    </services>
    <bindings configSource="Bindings.config">

    </bindings>
    <behaviors configSource="Behaviors.config">

    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <!-- other code removed for brevity -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: this is good information, but I was looking for putting it into complete separate as in class library and off course all the implementation and call from there so in case we decided to go for another application I don't have to do anything other then just call implementation classes from class library

Comment: also I am talking about client side not server side

Comment: The same still applies.  app domain is only going to use the main config. given the it's a class library, it is still executing in the one app domain and getting its setting from web.config.

Comment: I have manage to work, but can I put these config files externally outside ASP.NET MVC project

Comment: Play around with relative paths and see how it works. or try linking to it if the project allows for that.